# Issues in auth for Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Use Case: Create documents and drive files from server in backend, present file list querying drive SDK.

Used a service account, with drive SDK to create docs its flawless, working cool. 
Service Account: SOMEIDENTITY@developer.gserviceaccount.com

> credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
>   key,
>         scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')

Issue: There is no documented way to increase storage quotas of a service account.

Work Around: Suggested way for this is Drive Web Delegation, where the above server identity can be masked by a apps Google Account(drive@APPS_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN.com). And the quota available can be updated  at google Apps console for drive@APPS_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN.com. Its successful path for for all our work but there seems to be another issue with API here.

> credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
>   key,
>         scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', sub=user_email)

Issue: If we follow Drive Web Delegation, Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account, the auth to drive sdk for our service account fails in many cases and shows error in many user requests too for showing file list. Stack creation process happens, but its very slow because of many errors..

issue that shows up frequently.  This is not a drive issue, this is a part of Google Oauth2 authentication.

> URL being requested3:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?userIp=49.238.45.52
>
> Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
>
> Failed to retrieve access token: {   "error" : "invalid_request" }

I didnt find any sol for this, any idea how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Are you sure about the first issue? Setting sub=user_email should result in impersonation of that particular user and any quotas would apply to the impersonated user, not the service account. There is no way to increase the quota on a Service Account because it is not a 'real' Google user account.

Comment: In the first case we are not using sub=user_email, ya what you mentioned is right, we followed this to add avail the enhanced quota licenses associated to that  impersonated user. But sdk is not working properly...